# Testing OpenID authentication with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openid-connect, minikube

I have installed kubernetes with minikube in ubuntu 16.04. 
I want to know how i can integrate openid-connect based authentication with it. I am new to kubernetes. So any suggestion on how to configure would help.
I am currently accessing the dashboard with "minikube dashboard" command. But i dont seem to find any role specific login. The K8S guide has the below config section,

```
    kubectl config set-credentials USER_NAME \
   --auth-provider=oidc \
   --auth-provider-arg=idp-issuer-url=( issuer url ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=client-id=( your client id ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=client-secret=( your client secret ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=refresh-token=( your refresh token ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=idp-certificate-authority=( path to your ca certificate ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=id-token=( your id_token ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=extra-scopes=( comma separated list of scopes to add to "openid email profile", optional )
```

Can someone tell me how i can get values for

**1. Issuer URL
 2. Refresh token
 3. Id-token
 4. Extra-scope**

I assume the **client id** and **client secret** are the ones we get when **google credentials** are created. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The [Kubernetes Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/) docs try to explain the different "`authn`" plugins.  One of these is "OpenID Connect", which requires that you start up an "Identity Provider".

So when you tell `kubectl` to use `--auth-provider=oidc`, that's what you're using.  The `idp-issuer-url` will point at your Identity Provider's HTTPS URL.  They give different examples of implementations of this.  CoreOS has one called [Dex](https://github.com/coreos/dex).

Their repo has some examples under: `./examples`

An example of using [LDAP connector plugin for dex is here](https://github.com/SEJeff/k8s-ldap)

For more information about how Authentication is done in Kubernetes (e.g.: "What is authn?" "What is authz", etc...), there is a [great presentation by Eric Chiang here](https://youtu.be/i75ysFcvCkk).

So to answer your question:

#### Q: how i can get values for:

1. Issuer URL
2. Refresh token
3. Id-token
4. Extra-scope

#### A: [Set up Dex](https://github.com/SEJeff/k8s-ldap), then authenticate to it using the "Login" app (with some backend such as LDAP in example).  Then it redirects you to a page with a `~/.kube/config` file with a `user` which has all of these items.